# How can I grep a file for multiple unique values?

Tags: grep

I have some firewall logs and I want to find multiple unique values. I need to find every unique combination of source IP and destination port, which are in this format in /var/log/iptables.

```
SRC=123.123.123.123
DPT=137
```

So, if source IP 123.123.123.123 makes multiple appearances on multiple ports, I want to see that but, just once for each SRC/DPT combo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk solution might help. The first awk command combines each pair of successive `SRC` and `DPT` lines into a single line. The output from this command is then piped to the second awk command, which provides uniquefied output, retaining original order

```
awk '/^SRC|^DPT/{ORS=$0 ~ /^SRC/?" ":"\n"; print}' file.* | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

If multiple `SRC`, `DPT` entries exist per line, the following should work

```
grep -oE 'SRC=[[:digit:].]+[[:space:]]+DPT=[[:digit:].]+' file.txt | awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: Nope...I created a test file with SRC=123.123.123.123 DPT=137
SRC=123.123.123.123 DPT=137
SRC=123.123.123.123 DPT=137
SRC=123.123.123.123 DPT=137
SRC=123.123.123.1 DPT=137
SRC=123.123.12.23 DPT=17
SRC=123.123.123.12 DPT=13 and it pulled everything

Comment: @Gigahert, do you mind posting that test file snippet to your original question?

Comment: @Gigahert, added another option

Answer (score 0):

You can try "grep AND", see examples from the link:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/